# SQL sum up sales volume for different customer locations

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL-developer and I got the following output-table, which shows the monthly sales value of our customers. The customers have several locations.

| month | year | customer_name | sales_volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022 | Farming company Berlin | 150 |
| 01 | 2022 | Farming company London | 200 |
| 01 | 2022 | Farming company Amsterdam | 350 |
| 01 | 2022 | XY Company Berlin | 200 |
| 01 | 2022 | customer 5 | 7 |
| 01 | 2022 | customer 7 | 7 |
| 01 | 2022 | X_Person | 2 |
| 02 | 2022 | XY Company London | 100 |
| 02 | 2022 | Hello Company Berlin | 150 |
| 02 | 2022 | Hello Company Amsterdam | 150 |
| 02 | 2022 | customer 1 | 20 |
| 02 | 2022 | customer 2 | 10 |
| 02 | 2022 | customer 3 | 5 |
| 02 | 2022 | Y-Person | 1 |

Now I'd like to get the sales_volume per customer_name for month/year. I want to add the sales_volume per month/year for all the different locations of the Farming company, the XY Company and the Hello Company. The rest (customer 1-7, X-Person, Y-Person) should be summed up in an own row named "Other"

The new output table would be the following:

| month | year | customer_name | sum_Sales_volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022 | Farming Company | 700 |
| 01 | 2022 | XY Company | 300 |
| 01 | 2022 | Other | 16 |
| 02 | 2022 | XY Company | 100 |
| 02 | 2022 | Hello Company | 300 |
| 02 | 2022 | Other | 36 |

So far I tried to sum the customer_name with LIKE function but I don't understand how the "when then" works in this case.

My code:

```
Select 
month, 
year, 
sum(sales_volume)
CASE
    WHEN customer_name    LIKE  '%Farming%' Then 'Farming Company' 
    WHEN customer_name    LIKE  '%XY%' Then 'XY Company' 
    WHEN customer_name   LIKE  '%Hello%' Then 'Hello Company' 
    ELSE THEN 'Standard'
END AS "sum_Sales_volume"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how the "when then" works in this case.

In a `LIKE` comparison, `%` is a wildcard character that matches zero-or-more of any character.

So, for `WHEN customer_name LIKE '%Farming%'`, you are testing to see if the `customer_name` value has:

- The start-of-the-string; then
- Zero-or-more of any character; then
- The sub-string `Farming`; then
- Zero-or-more of any character; and
- Finally, the end-of-the-string.

If it matches then the value of the `THEN` clause of the `CASE` expression is returned; otherwise the next `WHEN` clause is tested and so on until if none of the `WHEN` clauses are matched then the value from the `ELSE` clause is returned.

---

> how can I sum up the values from the sales_volume column based on this string I'm searching in customer name.

Just use your `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
Select month, 
       year, 
       CASE
       WHEN customer_name LIKE '%Farming%'
       THEN 'Farming Company' 
       WHEN customer_name LIKE '%XY%'
       THEN 'XY Company' 
       WHEN customer_name LIKE '%Hello%'
       THEN 'Hello Company' 
       ELSE 'Standard'
       END AS customer_name,
       sum(sales_volume) AS sum_sales_volume
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       month, 
       year, 
       CASE
       WHEN customer_name LIKE '%Farming%'
       THEN 'Farming Company' 
       WHEN customer_name LIKE '%XY%'
       THEN 'XY Company' 
       WHEN customer_name LIKE '%Hello%'
       THEN 'Hello Company' 
       ELSE 'Standard'
       END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond! What I meant with "i don't understand how "when then" works in this case was: how can I sum up the values from the sales_volume column based on this string I'm searching in customer name. I looked through several tutorials, for instance https://learnsql.com/blog/case-when-with-sum/ but I couln't get a solution to the problem.  Something like: if customer contains "Farming" (what I'm doing with the wildcard character) then sum up all these sales_volumes and bring it back as "Sum_sales_volumes"

Answer (score 0):

As MTO already answered the question, but from the comment it seems there are some more things to explain I'll try to clarify some possible missunderstandings about LIKE() function with % wildcard and especially about CASE expression. All of the below code and results refers to your sample data.

- % wildcard character stands for (replaces) none or any string/array of characters
- Oracle character comparisons are case sensitive
  Just a few samples:

```sql
Select A_NAME From tbl Where A_NAME Like('%Berlin%');  -- any string containing 'Berlin' -with first capital letter
--  Result:   Farming company Berlin    
--            XY Company Berlin         
--            Hello Company Berlin

Select A_NAME From tbl Where A_NAME Like('%berlin%'); -- any string containing 'berlin' -with first small letter
--  Result: no rows selected

Select A_NAME From tbl Where A_NAME Like('%1');  --any string that ends with character '1' -including just '1'
--  Result:  customer 1

Select A_NAME From tbl Where A_NAME Like('cust%3');  --any string starting with 'cust' and ending with '3'
--  Result: customer 3

Select A_NAME From tbl Where A_NAME Like('Far%on');  -- any string starting with 'Far' and ending with 'on'
--  Result:  Farming company London
```

CASE expresssion - the most important thing to know is the fact that CASE evaluates WHEN conditions until the first one satisfied (True). When that happens CASE returns the value and ends checking possible other WHEN conditions. It is very important to have this in mind when using CASE with multiple WHEN conditions.
In the below code compare two CASE expressions selected - with coresponding values of columns DESCRIPTION_1 and DESCRIPTION_2. The ressulting differences are more than obvious and the only difference between the CASE expressions used is the order of WHEN conditions.

```sql
Select  A_MONTH, A_YEAR, A_NAME, VOLUME,
        CASE  WHEN VOLUME >= 100 THEN '100 plus' 
              WHEN VOLUME >= 200 THEN '200 plus'
              WHEN VOLUME >= 300 THEN '300 plus'
        ELSE 'less than 100'
        END "DESCRIPTION_1",
        CASE  WHEN VOLUME >= 300 THEN '300 plus' 
              WHEN VOLUME >= 200 THEN '200 plus'
              WHEN VOLUME >= 100 THEN '100 plus'
        ELSE 'less than 100'
        END "DESCRIPTION_2"
From tbl 

/*  R e s u l t :
A_MONTH     A_YEAR A_NAME                        VOLUME DESCRIPTION_1 DESCRIPTION_2
------- ---------- ------------------------- ---------- ------------- -------------
01            2022 Farming company Berlin           150 100 plus      100 plus      
01            2022 Farming company London           200 100 plus      200 plus      
01            2022 Farming company Amsterdam        350 100 plus      300 plus      
01            2022 XY Company Berlin                200 100 plus      200 plus      
01            2022 customer 5                         7 less than 100 less than 100 
01            2022 customer 7                         7 less than 100 less than 100 
01            2022 X_Person                           2 less than 100 less than 100 
02            2022 XY Company London                100 100 plus      100 plus      
02            2022 Hello Company Berlin             150 100 plus      100 plus      
02            2022 Hello Company Amsterdam          150 100 plus      100 plus      
02            2022 customer 1                        20 less than 100 less than 100 
02            2022 customer 2                        10 less than 100 less than 100 
02            2022 customer 3                         5 less than 100 less than 100 
02            2022 Y-Person                           1 less than 100 less than 100
*/
```

Hopefuly this could help you to better understand the % wildcard, LIKE() function and CASE expression and what to have in mind combining them.
Regards...